# Globals using Drupal with views

Tags: views, theming

I have a module in Drupal for getting the url extention via `$full_url = $GLOBALS['base_url'];`
Now, is it possible to make the full_url global so I can access it in the views module?

When I make a block using views I'm only getting 3 Global option:

- Global: Custom text
- Global: Math expression
- Global: View result counter
- here I want my full_url variable

Answer (score 1):

Views usage of the term "Global" is unrelated to PHP Globals. It means that is it globally accessible to all Views regardless of base type (node, user, taxonomy term).

If you find the need to use PHP in your Views, then you should either look into writing a custom Views handler, or try the [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

Answer (score 0):

When you select "node:path" from fields in a view, there is an option to make it absolute.